# Duplicate html in a ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, html

I have some HTML that will need to be duplicated in a number of places. If I externalize this to a text file and include it in the ASPX page, it would work but I will need to pass a parameter to this HTML (ClientID)

Without having to create a User control, is there a lighter way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

I would use a [master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) for this. Depending in the version of the framework(2.0+) [Nested  Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx) are also an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a raw aspx file with the HTML inside:

```
<%

If (Request.QueryString["ClientID"]) {
    // Do Something
}

%>

<p>HTML File Contents</p>
```

Then you could either server-side include the file or server.execute the file.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clarify how you pass a ClientID to "HTML", because it sounds like you're doing server-side processing to generate your HTML, which is a classic case of Ajax. I would recommend using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps standard #Includes still work, but TBH I haven't found any downside to master pages (as yet). This is what they were designed for.